# Dictionary data not send to web services in windows phone 7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I am new to windows phone 7. Is anyone have any idea of how to send dictionary data to webservices using HttpWebReqest.
Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods, 
1) Urlappending the data (this is possible only if your server accepts it).
2) Sending data through the body

For Further Reference Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The example in link sends only string data but i want to send dictionary data when content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded";